# Play VLC stream without interface

Tags: linux, internet, vlc-media-player, streaming, gui

I would like to use VLC to play an Internet radio stream without starting the GUI. Is that possible? I have explored the command line documentation for VLC a bit and I did not came to any solution.

So far I just invoke:

```
$ vlc <stream>
```

I am on Linux (Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: Which operating system is this on? It may help.

Comment: @MarshallConover You are absolutely right, just added it.

Comment: I don't know how VLC is packaged in Ubuntu, but you can try cvlc and nvlc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For playing vlc in the command line without launching a ui, it looks like [this page](https://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces/) has what you need.

Specifically, I think you want this command:

```
vlc --intf dummy vcd://
```

This specifies a dummy interface that never acually launches anything. I can't test this because I am away from my linux box right now, but here's the full command I think you're looking for:

```
vlc --intf dummy <stream>
```

Comment: You can add additional parameters to further configure the player. 
For example, if you'd like to hide the video title when it starts playing, and you want it to start in full screen along with a few other options. You can use something like: `vlc -I dummy --fullscreen --qt-minimal-view --no-qt-name-in-title <file>`

Answer (score 9):

To use vlc without interface, I just use this command:

cvlc stream

Comment: Best solution as it needs no extra options or switches.

Comment: As of 2021-12 and VLC Player 3.0.16 installed on macOS, there is no 'cvlc' command to be found.

Answer (score -1):

At the [VLC-documentation](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html#id338836), there is a great chapter about that:

Just choose the type of stream which fits your type of stream and fill in the correct `address` and `serverport`.

> ## Receiving a network stream
>
> **To receive an unicast UDP stream (sent by VLS or VLC's stream output),
>   start VLC with:**
>
> ```
> % vlc -vvv udp:[@:server_port]
> ```
>
> **To receive an multicast UDP stream (sent by VLS or VLC's stream
>   output), start VLC with:**
>
> ```
> % vlc -vvv udp:@multicast_address[:server_port]
> ```
>
> **To receive a HTTP stream, start VLC with :**
>
> ```
> % vlc -vvv http://www.example.org/your_file.mpg
> ```
>
> **To receive a RTSP stream, start VLC with:**
>
> ```
> % vlc -vvv rtsp://www.example.org/your_stream
> ```