# How to hard code a list of subtitles to a video using FFmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video

I would like to figure out how to stream a list of subtitles to an RTMP server.

The idea is I have a list of MP3 files and a list of subtitles. Each mp3 has its own subtitle. What I was trying to do is stream both lists and a video background (with the subtitles hardcoded to the video background) I tried a bunch of options

I managed to output them as an MP4 video with the subtitles soft coded but I couldn't figure out how to stream them with the subtitles hard coded, my lists goes as follow:

MP3s

```
file 'path/to/audio1.mp3'
file 'path/to/audio2.mp3'
file 'path/to/audio3.mp3'
file 'path/to/audio4.mp3'
...
```

Subtitles

```
file 'path/to/audio1.srt'
file 'path/to/audio2.srt'
file 'path/to/audio3.srt'
file 'path/to/audio4.srt'
...
```

And of course the video background as input

I was thinking about using a while loop but that's going to call ffmpeg for every MP3 which is inconvenient for a live stream.

With some more digging I come up with this code:

```bash
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i audioList.txt -f concat -safe 0 -i subtitleList.txt -i background/video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v][0:a]overlay[v1];[v1][2]subtitles[v2]" -map "[v2]" -c:a aac -b:a 128k -c:v h264 -b:v 3000k -f flv rtmp://stream/key
```

I’m not sure if the subtitles will be hardcoded because the script didn't work at all, it seems right to me but I’m getting this error:

```bash
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0xaaaacf52fb60]
No filename provided!
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xaaaacf5f6370] Error initializing filter 'subtitles'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I re-checked `subtitleList.txt` It seems right.

**Update/Edit:**
Thanks to @Hastur for suggesting the use of named pipes and to everyone who commented.

As I stated in the comments, there is another logic that will pick what audio and subtitles will be played, that's why using named pipes will be the best option for me.

I'm new to using named pipes with ffmpeg so I have some problems. Here is where I'm at right now:

After creating the pipes I use them in ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i audio.pipe -vf "subtitles=srt.pipe:force_style='Name=Default,Fontname=Arial,Fontsize=14,PrimaryColour=&H00ffffff,Shadow=0,Alignment=2,MarginL=1,MarginR=1,MarginV=100'" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -f flv rtmp://myRTMP
```

I write to the pipes by running `cat subtitle1.srt > srt.pipe & cat audio1.mp3 > audio.pipe`

Where I hit a wall right now is after sending new data to the pipes by executing `cat subtitle2.srt > srt.pipe` and `cat audio2.mp3 > audio.pipe` ffmpeg doesn't read the new data, there is an option for ffmpeg `-reconnect_at_eof` that tries to reconnect to a file after the current one ends (in this case the fifo pipe).

But I think it works only for one input, I used it for `audio.pipe` and it woked but I don't know how to specify it for `srt.pipe`.

Comment: What do you mean by "hardcoded"?

Comment: @mashuptwice burned (in the the frames of the video)

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser... and Merry Xmas. My suggestion is to act step by step: 1) start with one file mp3 and one subtitle. Put that output in a video. 2) do the same for a bunch of mp3 and srt. Put them always in a video. 3) put that video in the stream. 4) Merge all in a single command 5) Make it a script.

Comment: Hello @Hastur , That's a good idea, but I have tones of mp3s and I think ffmpeg is capable of achieving the results I wanted in one code, because the inputs are probably going to be dynamic, i just want to figure out how to achieve what i want then do the dynamic part.

Comment: @TheRedM well, if you try to get everything to work all at once you will not know what exact part is failing. Better to get every single step working by itself and later combine all the steps.

Comment: @mashuptwice exactly that's what i'm trying to do, if I can figure out first how to stream a hardcoded list of subtitles on top of a video background excluding audio that would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that with `-i` you can give a list of input and it is not required the input itself (video,audio,srt,...)? Each subtitle file is internally encoded with start and end timestamps for each sentence, as well as colors, fonts, etc.
If you have a series of them, how are you going to synchronize them with the audio and video? _You want it all, you want it now._ It is not an approach that pays off on complex problems. The way to solve it, is to break it down into smaller pieces, which are probably already solved. As often happens in these cases, there are more ways to reach your goal.

Comment: @TheRedM I do not think `concat` can handle multiple subtitle files in serialized order. Subtitle files usually contain time information. You probably need to parse the subtitles beforehand with different software and concatenate them with new time information.

Comment: @mashuptwice it worked for me for softcoded subtitles, note that my .srt subtitle file contains only one text with the length of the mp3 file as the ending time of the subtitle, using ```concat``` option tells ffmpeg to play every mp3 subtitle with the corresponding subtitle, the .srt paths in the .txt file are the same order on the other .txt file

Comment: What do you mean by softcoded subtitles?

Comment: @Hastur Yeah it works with a .txt list of inputs, i tried it for softcoded subtitles, I already figured out how to hardcode it by just putting ```- i subtitles.srt``` in ```-vf``` and using ```force_style``` in ```-vf``` the next step is archiving the same result with a .txt list of .srt paths, I don't know how to tell ```-vf``` that ```-i SubtitlesList.txt``` is a list of subtitles, that's where I hit a wall

Comment: @mashuptwice softcoded subtitles means that you can turn them on/off when the video is playing, in supported media players like VLC, similar to how you can turn off/on subtitles on YouTube

Comment: @TheRedM Ok, then [edit] your question and add the command lines that work with the description of how they work, and the wall that stops you. BTW since you know VLC why do not use it? With a list of mp3 and subtitles with the same filename (start in the same directory of the mp3) you should be able to easily stream them... maybe even without `ffmpeg`. You can also use playlist and modify them.

Comment: @Hastur I will edit it, I'm not using VLC because i'm on a headless server, also ffmpeg give me more control of what I will do next after figuring out the hardcoding part (the plan is to stream it to Facebook, and using Facebook api and some other logic will run a poll asking viewers what to play next)

Comment: You may find interesting also [this](https://superuser.com/a/664882/257269) on the use of vlc without [interface](https://wiki.videolan.org/Interfaces/) e.g. `vlc --intf dummy <stream>`, after that you install just the core of vlc. For the user interaction of your example you can find so many ways to do it (give it a look to _fifo pipe_ for example with `man fifo` under Linux). Good Luck